# Exception not throwing my string-- it's throwing the literal exception instead of my throw

Tags: javascript

I'm practicing with try/catch. Why isn't the output for the empty array exception "No scores were entered"? It's spitting out "average=NaN" instead. Thank you as always for the help!

Output:

Average = 84.75

Average = 76

Scores cannot be less than 0

Average = NaN

Only integers can be entered.

```js
// Returns the average of the numbers in the scores array.
function findAverage(scores) {
   var sum = 0;
   
      for (var score of scores){
         if(score < 0){
            throw "Scores cannot be less than 0";
            }
         }
         
      if (scores === []){
         throw "No scores were entered.";
         }
         
      for (score of scores){
         if (Number.isInteger(score)===false){
          throw "Only integers can be entered.";  
            }
         }
      
   
   scores.forEach(function(score) {      
      sum += score;
   });
   return sum / scores.length;
   
}

console.log("Average = " + findAverage([90, 85, 71, 93]));
console.log("Average = " + findAverage([76]));

try{
console.log("Average = " + findAverage([90, -85, 71, 93]));   // Should not accept negative numbers
}
catch(exception){
   console.log(exception);
   }
   
try{
   console.log("Average = " + findAverage([]));            // Should not accept empty arrays
   }
catch(exception) {
   console.log(exception);
   }

try{
console.log("Average = " + findAverage([60, "cat", 70]));     // Should not accept non-numbers
}
catch(exception){
   console.log(exception);
   }
```

Comment: when writing `scores === []` you are comparing two objects, and they always be different ; use `scores.length == 0` as test

Comment: Ah, that is very helpful. You are so smart!! Thank you! It worked :)

Comment: The result of the expression `console.log("Average = " + findAverage([90, -85, 71, 93]));` does not throw an error/exception, ergo your `catch` is not triggered.

Comment: `scores.length < 1` or `JSON.stringify(scores) === '[]'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make the following changes in the `if` statement. Check if it is an array and check the length to make sure it is not 0.

```js
// Returns the average of the numbers in the scores array.
function findAverage(scores) {
   var sum = 0;
   
      for (var score of scores){
         if(score < 0){
            throw "Scores cannot be less than 0";
            }
         }
         
      if (!Array.isArray(scores) || scores.length === 0){
         throw "No scores were entered.";
         }
         
      for (score of scores){
         if (Number.isInteger(score)===false){
          throw "Only integers can be entered.";  
            }
         }
      
   
   scores.forEach(function(score) {      
      sum += score;
   });
   return sum / scores.length;
   
}

console.log("Average = " + findAverage([90, 85, 71, 93]));
console.log("Average = " + findAverage([76]));

try{
console.log("Average = " + findAverage([90, -85, 71, 93]));   // Should not accept negative numbers
}
catch(exception){
   console.log(exception);
   }
   
try{
   console.log("Average = " + findAverage([]));            // Should not accept empty arrays
   }
catch(exception) {
   console.log(exception);
   }

try{
console.log("Average = " + findAverage([60, "cat", 70]));     // Should not accept non-numbers
}
catch(exception){
   console.log(exception);
   }
```